# Adding spaces on word boundaries in text extraction with lxml

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml

An example from `lxml.html` documentation:

```
>>> from lxml import html
>>> root = html.fragment_fromstring('<p>Hello<br>world!</p>')
>>> html.tostring(root,method='text')
'Helloworld!'
```

My question: is there any easy (or "right") way for producing `'Hello world!'` string instead?

Comment: I would try to replace the ``<br>`` tag with ``" "`` before converting the parsed HTML to string... I do not know lxml so I cannot say how you can achieve it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
from lxml import html
doc = html.document_fromstring('<p>Hello<br>world!</p>')

for br in doc.xpath("*//br"):
    br.tail = " " + br.tail if br.tail else " "

doc.text_content()
```

This prints:

```
'Hello world!'
```

Comment: I get the idea... yet I'm looking for a _generic_ approach. Like, what about text in `<p>` tags; any other tag? IMHO the best solution would be telling `tostring()` the 'separator' character, like in `join()`

Comment: Well, telling it the separator character is trivial, you can write your own function to do just that with a simple replace or some regex. The issue is how to decide what to replace with a delimiter? Because a <br> is by all means a different character then a space, an should be treated as such. You might be thinking it is obvious to replace this, but this is just in your case. Other cases have other requirements, and no case is "natural" enough to implement such behaviour. Nevertheless, these specific cases are easily implemented adhoc via xpath, regex and other string manipulations.

Comment: I agree. In my case I simply ended up replacing `*//br` with `//*` and then replacing `\s+` with a single space with `re`. Thanks!